# How to filter measures in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to filter the measure values as

```
MeasureA   MeasureB
 10          10
 15          15
  5          20
 20          20
```

Here I need to get only the measures are not equal, I am using filter function as but not working

> Select Filter({[Measures].[A], 
>                  [Measures].[B]}, 
>                  ([Measures].[A]-
>                       [Measures].[B])=0)
>                       on 0
>                       from [Cube]

Expected result set

```
    MeasureA   MeasureB     
     5          20
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try creating a calculated field in the DSV for this Fact table...

```
CASE
  WHEN MeasureFieldA != MeasureFieldB THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Then you can create a "fact dimension" and have this calculated field as an attribute to be used in your queries or calculated measures.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a dimension instead of your measures for the first part of the filter statement. Assuming you are querying products then your query might look like:

```
select {[Measures].[A],[Measures].[B]} on columns,
filter ({[Products].Members},[Measures].[A] = [Measures].[B]) on rows
from [Sales Cube]
```